# Entity Framework - stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
create Procedure procLoc
AS
BEGIN
      select 
          pr.name, loc.address
      from 
          Profile pr 
      join 
          Location loc on pr.id = loc.id
END
```

For the add function Import dialog box that comes up, there are the following options

- None
- Scalars
- Complex
- Entities

Which option would I select in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your stored procedure is returning multiple values: `pr.name,loc.address`, you'll only have 2 choices- Complex or Entities.  If you already have an entity mapped with Name/Address properties you can choose it, otherwise choose complex.  I usually click the `Get Column Information` button and then `Create New Complex type` and let it generate one for me.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Linq to SQL was so much easier. You just dropped it and Linq to SQL did all the work.